# do we have to initialize Xamarin.Forms in MvvmCross in Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am having a simple sample in `MvvmCross`. In that, I have installed `Xamarin.Forms version 3.4` and `MvvmCross version 6.6.`

My doubt is:

1. What is the purpose of initializing this code  `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle) in android Renderer ?`
2. Do we have to initialize Xamarin.Forms in  MvvmCross version 6.6 in android renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of initializing this code `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle)` in android renderer?

If you check the `Xamarin.Forms` [official quote on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/hello-xamarin-forms/deepdive?pivots=windows) it goes something like this:

> The OnCreate override initializes the `Xamarin.Forms` framework by calling the Init method. This causes the Android-specific implementation of `Xamarin.Forms` to be loaded in the application before the `Xamarin.Forms` application is loaded. In addition, the `MainActivity` class stores a reference to itself in the Instance property. The Instance property is known as the local `context` and is referenced from the PhoneDialer class.

The quote is self-explanatory but just to help you a little bit it is basically used to load the Android specific implementation that Xamarin.Forms Framework needs at Runtime.

> do we have to initialize Xamarin.Forms in MvvmCross version 6.6 in android renderer?

No, you do not need to initialize this in MvvmCross, as MvvmCross does it for you in the background. For more information on how to setup MvvmCross for Xamarin.Forms check [this](https://medium.com/@martijn00/using-mvvmcross-with-xamarin-forms-part-1-eaee5815bb8c)

Comment: Where would I put the Inits required for some nuget packages then? They sometime ask it to be called before Xamarin.Forms's init.

Comment: Well, they usually say that because some people use plugins directly on the App class's constructor which causes issues in their libraries since it's not initialized but directly used. So they ask you to init it before calling XF init so their libraries are ready @AmirHajiha Not everyone who uses XF usually understands the internal working of XF/C# so they do that to avoid confusion for new users.